# Confused with Same Origin Policy of Browsers

Tags: javascript, security, web, cookies, csrf

As we know, the browsers' same origin policy forbidden `async` request to the foreign origin. This policy's purpose is to prevent `CSRF` attack.

But we can still request to the foreign origin synchronously, and the browser will take on the target website's cookie, then `CSRF` happens again.
Exp. We can add a hidden form in the hacker's website, and automatic submit the request to the target website.

So is this policy necessary ?

Comment: "_But we can still request to the foreign origin synchronously_" Can we really?

Comment: @Teemu . Exp. We can add a hidden form in the hacker's website, and automatic submit the request to the target website.

Comment: Not sure if I understood the question ... If we can add a hidden form in the hacker's website, that means we are the hacker ..?

Comment: @Teemu the hacker can do this to attack the target website

Comment: Note that the same origin policy does not prevent CSRF in ajax requests. It's only the response that doesn't get back to the attacker, but in these cases he doesn't care, the request is made and processed on the victim server.

Answer (score 0):

To close a CSRF Attack its common to use a token which will be checked afterwards. So the attacking site with the hidden form does not know the token since its putted into the code of the foreign website. The same origin policy will prevent to read out page of the foreign site so you will never get the token with an async call

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery